# Запятая перед "в общем"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Такое предложение: "Сама себе и продавец, и заведующая, одна в общем" - запятая перед "в общем" нужна? А то в тексте не стоит, и я начинаю сомневаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении знаки нужно поставить по-другому:

**Сама себе и продавец, и заведующая - одна, в общем.**

Запятая нужна, она выделяет вводное слово со значением "вообще говоря".

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна. Хотя *в общем* здесь вводное.

Запятая не ставится, потому что все сочетание *одна в общем* является пояснительной конструкцией.

> Если вводное слово стоит в конце
> обособленного оборота – запятые
> ставятся перед обособленным оборотом и
> после него. Перед вводным словом
> запятая не ставится.

См. п.2, пп. В [link text](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/)

Comment: Вопрос в том, есть ли здесь обособленный оборот. Думаю, что нет.

Comment: Вопрос терминологии. Можно сказать "обособленная конструкция", смысл тот же. Например, деепричастный оборот в некоторых пособиях называется "деепричастной конструкцией".

Answer (score 0):

По Розенталю, слово "в общем" не является вводным, если употребляется в значении "в целом, всегда, постоянно", поэтому в данном предложении запятая не нужна

Comment: Здесь явно не смысле "всегда", а в смысле - "короче говоря". То есть вводное.